# How to write the content of a json file to an excel file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a bit complicated looking json file that stores a dictionary.
[image: Please refer to this image.]

Here is the dictionary if you want to code on your local machine.

```js
{'https://www.linkedin.com/in/manashi-sherawat-mathur-phd-3a97b69': 
{'showallexperiences': 
[{'company_url': 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/1612/'}, 
{'company_url': 'https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=Independent+Pharma%2FBiotech+Professional'], 'showalleducation': 
[{'university_url': 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/3555/'}, {'university_url': None}]}, 
'https://www.linkedin.com/in/baneshwar-singh-6143082b/': 
{'showallexperiences': 
[{'company_url': 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/166810/'}, 
{'company_url': 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/166810/'}], 
'showalleducation': 
[{'university_url': 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/6737/'}, {'university_url': 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/5826549/'}]}}}
```

The main keys of the dictionary are different Linkedin URLs and their values are also dictionaries each storing company and university URLs belonging to that link.

I need to write the content of that dictionary to an excel file.

Particularly, each different Linkedin URL (the main key)'s info should be written on a separate row.
I also hope to add some numbering for the columns of different company's and university's urls.
[image: So that the final output looks like this.]

Can somebody please suggest any solution?

Comment: Did you try to import the JSON File Into an XLSX File directly? Was the result different from what you expected or wanted?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. My suggestion is to use the Pandas library.
If you have tried to write your own code, show it so that I can guide you.

Comment: @Skapis9999 Yes,  I have tried that. But the problem is that all he LinkedIn URLs happen to be written on the same row. And of course the column names remain the same whereas I wanted to change the column names for each different key (company url and university url).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "https://www.linkedin.com/in/manashi-sherawat-mathur-phd-3a97b69": {
        "showallexperiences": [
            {"company_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/1612/"},
            {
                "company_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=Independent+Pharma%2FBiotech+Professional"
            },
        ],
        "showalleducation": [
            {"university_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/3555/"},
            {"university_url": None},
        ],
    },
    "https://www.linkedin.com/in/baneshwar-singh-6143082b/": {
        "showallexperiences": [
            {"company_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/166810/"},
            {"company_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/166810/"},
        ],
        "showalleducation": [
            {"university_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/6737/"},
            {"university_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/5826549/"},
        ],
    },
}

all_data = []
for k, v in data.items():
    company_urls = {
        f"exp{i}_company_url": e["company_url"]
        for i, e in enumerate(v["showallexperiences"], 1)
    }

    edu_urls = {
        f"edu{i}_uni_url": e["university_url"]
        for i, e in enumerate(v["showalleducation"], 1)
    }

    all_data.append({"linkedin_link": k, **company_urls, **edu_urls})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

| linkedin_link | exp1_company_url | exp2_company_url | edu1_uni_url | edu2_uni_url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://www.linkedin.com/in/manashi-sherawat-mathur-phd-3a97b69 | https://www.linkedin.com/company/1612/ | https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=Independent+Pharma%2FBiotech+Professional | https://www.linkedin.com/company/3555/ |  |
| https://www.linkedin.com/in/baneshwar-singh-6143082b/ | https://www.linkedin.com/company/166810/ | https://www.linkedin.com/company/166810/ | https://www.linkedin.com/company/6737/ | https://www.linkedin.com/company/5826549/ |

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]